# Using ui-view and states

Tags: angularjs, controller, view, states

in my app.js folder I have a

```
$stateProvider
        .state('state1', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/list.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl1',
        })
        .state('state2', {
            url: '/details',
            templateUrl: 'app/details.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl2'
        })
        .state('state3', {
            url: '/list',
            templateUrl: 'app/list.html',
            controller: 'Ctrl3'
        });
```

At the moment I am calling all of these altogether in index.html using

Is there a way to specify which controller you want displayed in each part of the page. As I'm calling it now it seems that it simply calls everything where it is called in the index.html page which makes it quite hard to organise.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router read this there is everything you need

Comment: If I understand your question correctly this is what you want: http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Comment: Thanks, friends. I found the answer in those documents.